# How to run a program in R language using terminal and to see the output

Tags: r

Using putty, I installed the terminal environment. Here I want to run an R program which may produce some graph or plots. What are the commands to run such a R program? What are the commands to create the directory and see the output of such a R program?

Comment: Are you using putty to connect from a Windows PC to a remote machine? You need an X server on your desktop machine to view graphics from the remote machine. http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html

Comment: Yes. I am using putty to connect from a Windows PC to a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your R script in batch mode.

```
R CMD BATCH your_script.R your_scripts_output.txt
```

I'm not sure that you can view plots in terminal mode. However you can save the plots to an image (png, pdf, ...)

Comment: `Rscript` is probably preferable.

Comment: I used the XShell Xmanager and I finally got the plots in bmp format. Please suggest the command for plotting the graphs in eps format or to save them in eps format.